# Ruby why does rackup raise this undefined method error upon boot?

Tags: ruby

I have a class for writing recurring entries. The initializer verifies that the start date (`@date_1`) is after the end date (`@date_2`).

```rb
class Recurrent 

    include Format

    attr_accessor :intitule, :categorie, :sens
    attr_reader :mensualite, :date_1, :date_2

    def initialize (user, date_1, date_2 = date_1.next_year)
        @date_1 = date_1
        @date_2 = date_2
        @jour = Date.today
        @user = user
        @compte = @user.compte
        # start date before end date ? :
        inversees?
    end

# cut for brievity

    private

    def inversees?
        if @date_1 < @date_2
            return true
        else
            raise StandardError.new("start date must be before end date.")
        end
    end

    begin
        inversees?(false)
        rescue => error
        puts error.message
    end
end
```

when I start the server I get this error message :

```
[me@manjaro accountsapp]$ rackup 
undefined method `inversees?' for Recurrent:Class
```

Although, when I provoke the error by entering wrong dates (and disabling the javascript test that I do before data is sent to the server) , I does work. Why does this error message appear?

Comment: I assume your `begin`-`end` block is within the class definition. (Your code does not have an `end` for the class definition.) When `inversees?(false)` is executed (while the class is being constructed) `self` is `Recurrent`, so Ruby is looking for a class method `inversees?`. It finds none, so raises the exception you saw. You have only defined an *instance method* `inversees?`, which is invoked on an instance of `Recurrent`, not on the class itself.

Comment: Yes the `begin-end` block is within the class definition. I updated the code accordingly. I would never call `inversees?` on the class (`Recurrent.inversees?`) but only in instances of the class. When I change this to `self.inversees?`, I get a nomethod error on the instance of the class : `#<Recurrent:0x0000559524c1ac78 `. I don't see how to make the error upon server boot go away.

Comment: If you keep `def inverses?...` you can only invoke `inverses?(false)` on class instances. Because it is private it must be invoked with an implicit receiver, `self`, when `self` equals an instance, which would be from within an instance method; if you change that to `def self.inverses?...` you can only invoke it on the class, and because it is private, only with an implicit receiver, (`inverses?(false)`) when `self` equals `Recurrent`. The latter would be as in your code or within a class method...

Comment: Note that you could define both an instance method `def inverses?...` and a class method `def self.inverses?...`. The fact that they have the same name is irrelevant (in the same way that `Array#to_s` is unrelated to `Hash#to_s`).

Comment: The error will of course go away if you remove the `begin`-`end` block. What is the purpose of that block, considering that it only concerns the class and not instances? (Time for bed. Will check back in the morn.)

Comment: I need the `begin - end` block to avoid the creation of the instance if the dates are wrong. I could of course remove it and simply return `false`. It is clear that `begin - end` is raised on the class, not on the instance and therefore a class method is required.

Comment: Sorry, no you don't return false on an instantiation. I move the verification method `inversees?` to instance methods, rather than trying to avoid instantiation if incorrect data is provided.